# windows powershell/vscode not prompting for git credentials

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code

Powershell is not prompting me for my git credentials when I try to do a git clone and just gives me an Authentication failed error.  This is also true when I use VSCode's integrated terminal.

```
Test2> git clone https://bitbucket....
Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket....'
```

However, this is not an issue when using MobaXterm.

```
Test2> git clone https://bitbucket....
Cloning into 'repo'...
Username for 'https://bitbucket....':
```

What can I do to powershell/vscode so I get prompted for my git credentials.  Thanks!

Comment: What does `git config --get credential.helper` say?

Comment: It says `manager-core`

Comment: That means it'll use Windows' Credential Manager for creds. You can open Credential Manager and remove any cached credentials for the remote domain in question, and it should prompt you on next `git clone`. Alternatively, unset the config opion (`git config --unset credential.helper`) and git will start prompting you everytime.

Comment: Thanks, but running the unset command still does not prompt me for my credentials. I looked at Windows Credential Manager and did not see any bitbucket or git related entries.  When I run unset, credential.helper still shows `manager-core` as the helper.   I even tried adding `--global`

Comment: Got it working.  For some reason I had to run PowerShell as Administrator before running `git config --system --unset credential.helper`. Thanks Mathias!